# Only user edit there own document in document library Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

**> \Only user edit there own document in document library Sharepoint

> How can i restrict user Only edit there own document in document library Sharepoint 2013 ???**

Comment: Guid me for only edit setting

Answer (score 0):

There is the setting, only user can see his documents in advance settings of list.

If still you want to give read only access to all and only edit to author... for that, you need to write custom event hander (item Updating)